# return from eachRow() cassandra-driver for nodejs

Tags: node.js, cassandra-2.0, datastax-enterprise

In my node application, i am using following code to run some query. I want to call callback function after (arraySize > 100) and exit. Currently i can only exit after all processing is complete.

```
var matchedUsers = [];
client.eachRow(query, [], { prepare : true }, function (n, row) { 
      if(someCondition){
        matchedUsers.push(row.x);
      }

      if(matchedUsers.length>100){
        //exit here
      }
     }, function (err) {
        callback(matchedUsers)
     } );
```

Comment: You should express your condition in CQL. But yes you can do that by setting the `fetchSize` in options to `101` and then you can call `result.nextPage` if available (it will be available if another page is available in the end callback)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver/blob/f465a1488a1fd29d050c0856cdf73c7daa5045e3/lib/client.js) is the underlying implementation of eachRow:

If I am reading through their node.js driver correctly, the whole cassandra result is returned back to you based on the query your provide. So you might as well just add all of the results to your own data structure, and then just iterate through it to look for your match(and of course just break out of your loop when match is found).